# Swift: pass data to first child of NavigationController instantiate with storyboardID

Tags: swift

I want to pass data to the first `viewController` which is embeded in `navigationController`.

To access this navigation controller it has a `storyBoardID`, I arrive at instantiate `navigationController` but I can not pass him data,

Here is my code:

```
extension UINavigationController {

func dismissAndPresentNavigationController(from storyboard: UIStoryboard?, identifier: String) {
    guard let navigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? UINavigationController else { return }

    print("OK")
    if let nav = navigationController.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? ChatBotViewController{
        print("OK2")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

The identifier that I put in parameter is the `storyBoardID` of the navigation controller.

How to transmit data to the first controller of `navigationcontroller`?

**SOLUTION:**

```
extension UINavigationController {

func dismissAndPresentNavigationController(from storyboard: UIStoryboard?, identifier: String, with fittoBottle: FittoBottle) {
    guard let navigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? UINavigationController else { return }

    if let nav = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ChatBotViewController{
        nav.fittoBottle = fittoBottle
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why are you dismissing self and then attempting to present the navigation controller from it? Does that work?

Comment: Because my app contains 2 navigation controller, which I finished with the first I want to move to the second may I do not want to leave open the first so I close, And yes it works

Comment: What is `self` in this context? Are you in a `UIViewController` subclass or a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Look my edit I forgot to put this is important, it's UINavigationController extension.
When I call the function I call it from my first navigationcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After instantiating the navigation controller from the storyboard, you will be able to access the root view controller via `navigationController.viewControllers.first`.

```
guard let navigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? UINavigationController else { return }

if let chatBotViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ChatBotViewController {
    chatBotViewController.fittoBottle = fittoBottle
}

self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? The ChatBotViewController doesn't get the `fittoBottle` value?

Comment: Yes chatbotViewController does not get fittoBottle value.

Comment: He does not enter the in  condition if let nav = navigationController.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? ChatBotViewController

Comment: The navigation controller you instantiate probably doesn't have a navigation controller of it's own. Try just `navigationController.viewControllers.first` if you want the root view controller of the navigation controller you instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between view controllers in an iOS app, the best way is using `protocol` (delegate) or `Notification`. In you case, extending an UINavigationController doesn't sound a good idea, because you shouldn't relay on extension methods to instance view controller and then passing any data to it, and as an extension method, it's not the responsibility for an UINavigationController to take care about `ChatBotViewController` or any other instanced controllers.

For my suggestion, in anywhere you want to show the ChatBotViewController, in your storyboard, create a presenting modal segue to the ChatBotViewController (which is embedded in an UINavigationController), and use `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` to initiate the navigation controller, and override `prepare(for:sender:)` to set the data you want to pass in your ChatBotViewController.

Here's some codes for explaining:

```
import UIKit

struct FittoBottle {

}

class ChatBotViewController: UIViewController {

  var fittoBottle = FittoBottle()

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  func showChatController() {

    /*
     If there is any controller is presented by this view controller
     or one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy,
     we will dismiss it first.
     */
    if presentedViewController != nil {

      dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.showChatController()
      }
      return

    }

    // Data that will be sent to the new controller
    let fittoBottle = FittoBottle()

    // ChatBotViewControllerSegue is the segue identifier set in your storyboard.
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChatBotViewControllerSegue", sender: fittoBottle)


  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else {
      return
    }

    guard let chatBotController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ChatBotViewController else {
      return
    }

    // Get the data from sender, if not found, create it there.
    // Or if you don't pass it through sender, you can specify it here.
    let fittoBottle = sender as? FittoBottle ?? FittoBottle()
    chatBotController.fittoBottle = fittoBottle


  }

}
```